# python opencv circle detection

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image with two unfilled circles, the code fills them and I want the code to also show me the coordinates of each circles center. I've tried doing this, but my code doesn't seem to work. Any help on this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im_in = cv2.imread("circle.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

th, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_in, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

im_floodfill = im_th.copy()


h, w = im_th.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)

cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0, 0), 255)

im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)

im_out = im_th | im_floodfill_inv

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(im_out, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

        cv2.drawContours(im_out, [contour], 0, 255, -1)

        cv2.putText(im_out, f'({cX}, {cY})', (cX - 30, cY - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 255, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite("circles_filled_with_coordinates.png", im_out)
```

[image: circle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to flood fill. You can get the centroids without doing that in Python/OpenCV as follows:

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold
- Get external contours
- For each contour, get the centroids and draw them on a copy of the input as well as the drawing the contours
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('2circles.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# get centroids and draw contours
result = img.copy()
for c in contours:
    # get centroids
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    print("cx:", cx, "cy:", cy)
    # draw contour on input
    cv2.drawContours(result,[c],0,(0,0,255),2)
    # draw centroids
    xx = int(cx)
    yy = int(cy)
    rr = 1
    cv2.circle(result, (xx,yy), rr, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('2circles_centroids.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Centroids:

```
cx: 529 cy: 355
cx: 230 cy: 200
```

Centroids and Contour on Input:

[image]